# Gdal: How to conditionally assign a new value to pixels of a raster image?

Tags: image-processing, gis, gdal, ogr

**Given a topographic GIS raster** of one country `crop.tif`:

```
# download:
curl -o ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
# unzip:
unzip ETOPO1.zip
# crop:
gdal_translate -projwin -005.50 051.30 10.00 041.00 ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tif crop.tif
```

**Given an elevation threshold** n = 50 (meters)

**How to set the value of all pixels where z >= n to 50 ?**

---

Related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300210/, [Gdal: How to get a pixel's value from raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69066/)

**Help?:** gdallocationinfo can get the value of one point (without iterating the whole image):

```
$ gdallocationinfo crop.tif 1 1 -valonly
> 73
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `gdal_calc.py`. By example :

```
gdal_calc.py -A crop.tif --outfile=level0100.tif --calc="100*(A>100)"     --NoDataValue=0
```

to read as : `given an input -A (crop.tif), with output level0100.tif, when a pixel have a first band's value A>100 set value to 100. Else, set is as 0.

Within `--calc=""`, you may set other conditions. If you want to set values such 100 < v < 200 to 100, then :

```
gdal_calc.py -A crop.tif --outfile=level0100.tif --calc="100*(100<A<200)"     --NoDataValue=0
```

should work. (this last one was not tested)