# How to assign values to pixel based on condition

Tags: gdal

I would like to change the values of the pixel of a `geotiff` raster such as is `1` if the pixel values are between `50` and `100` and `0` otherwise.

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315096/gdal-how-to-conditionally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image), this is what I am doing:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif --calc="1*(50<=A<=100)" --NoDataValue=0
```

but I got the following error

```
0.. evaluation of calculation 1*(50<=A<=100) failed
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think such a notation would only work if the expression returns a single boolean, but this returns an array of booleans. Hence the suggestion to aggregate the array to a scalar with something like `any()` or `all()`.

You should be able to write it in a way compatible with Numpy arrays with something like this:

```py
1 * ((50 <= A) & (A <=100))
```

Your original expression has an implicit `and` in it, whereas this uses an explicit `&` which translates to `np.logical_and` for an element-wise test if both values on either side are True.

I'm not sure what the multiplication with one adds in this case, it casts the `bool` to an `int32` datatype. Even if you need to write the result as an `int32` you can probably still leave the casting to GDAL in this case.

A toy example replicating this would be:

```py
a = np.random.randint(0,2,5, dtype=np.bool_)
b = np.random.randint(0,2,5, dtype=np.bool_)
```

With this data `a and b` would fail in the same way, because it can't evaluate an entire array as True/False, whereas `a & b` would return a new array with the element-wise result.